# Do you have to be at least 13 to sign in with a Google account?

Tags: pokemon-go

Do you have to be at least the age of 13 to sign in with a Google account, or was the Google option not showing up because it was a glitch?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Option should still be available to you even if you input an age of under 13. Google isn't one of those platforms that contain certain things not suitable for a young child (well, most of the time).

**so it was most likely a glitch. Signing in to Google should be an option.**

Comment: Do you have evidence that signing in with a Google account is an option for those under 13? Google claims to disallow children from having accounts, so it would make sense for this option to be hidden from anyone below the allowed age. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1350409?hl=en

Comment: I mean I've had an account on google since I was 12, so I'm pretty sure they should allow it